# DeviceNotFound when deploy in hybrid apps on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have an app developed with hybrid apps (cordova) in VS 2013 Update 3, I have successfully installed the app on Android and iOS, but when I try to install it on Windows Phone 8.1 I get the exception: "**Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException**". Of course the phone is connected via USB to my computer, I'm following these steps (as stated on the MSDN site):

"Follow these instructions to run your app on a Windows Phone device that is connected to your PC
**To run your app on a device**

1. With your app open in Visual Studio, choose Windows Phone 8 or
   Windows Phone (Universal) from the Solution Platforms list. If you
   don’t see this option, choose Solution Platforms from the Add/Remove
   Buttons list to display it.

   2. Choose Device.
   3. Press F5 to start the app.

Visual Studio starts the app on the connected Windows Phone device."

I'm not sure If I have to do something else either on my project or on my phone (by the way, it's a Lumia 630).
Please help!

Comment: does it also happen with VS2013 Update 4?

Comment: I haven´t tried with the update 4, I installed that update on another computer and it broke the project, I'm using AngularJS and I think it has to do with that. Anyway, do you think it has to do with the update 3?

Comment: Correction, is not AngularJS the problem. is the update on hybrid-apps included in the update 4

Comment: Refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_UsingtheWindowsPhoneDeveloperRegistrationTool to make sure your phone is unlocked. You might also find this helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_device

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will review them